# 'ImageFormat' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Drawing.Imaging'

Tags: asp.net, aspose

I've just upgraded the Aspose packages within one of our ASP.Net systems and stumbled across a weird issue - a couple of ambiguous reference style errors, instinctively I attempted the fix of fully qualifying the reference...but it still doesn't seem to have fixed it.

One instance is this particular `if` block:

```
If converter.HasNextImage() Then
    converter.GetNextImage(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileToConvert) & "\" & Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileToConvert) & "_small" & suffix, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg, newWidth, newHeight, 75)
End If
```

Where `ImageFormat` is supposedly ambiguous. I suspect it's something to do with the `Aspose.Imaging` DLL, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Has anyone else got a solution other than just binning the `Aspose.Imaging` DLL?

UPDATE: After systematically removing the suspected DLLs it seems to be the `Aspose.Drawing` DLL that is the problem

Comment: Could you please create a standalone sample VS.NET application (using Aspose.Drawing API), zip the project with resource files and share us via some file sharing service (Dropbox,  Google chrome,  etc.) to reproduce the issue, we will check it soon. 

You may also post your issue or queries @ dedicated forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/drawing/44).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AmjadSahi - Unfortunately I can't create a standalone app to the same spec because there isn't an installer for a version of Visual studio old enough to create the relevant project type; however this seems closest https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-drawing-version-22-4-0-0-and-system-drawing-common-version-5-0-0-2-conflicts/246587

Comment: We recommend using latest versions of the Aspose APIs if it fix your issue. If you still find the issue, you may post your issue suggested forums.

Comment: @AmjadSahi - the issue was caused by upgrading to the latest APIs. I would post it on your forums, but I don't have access to an Aspose account (I wasn't working here when the company subscribed - so I wasn't allocated an account on your portal)

Comment: You can create another account based on any email and then post your issue with sample project with resource files in the respective Aspose forums as devised earlier.